# How to create a mega menu by modules in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, megamenu

I'm a beginner Magento.
Now I'm trying create a mega menu in Magento 1 use modules
I'm using Magento 1.9.3.2 and sample data 1.x to work with Magento.
So What should i do to solve this problem? Not use plugin and admin panel.
Thanks advanced.

Comment: Use any mega menu from magento connect https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=mega+menu&pl=0

Comment: Thankk man. Let's me try :D :D

Comment: But I need create a new mega menu by modules.
Create on phpStorm. Don't use the available themes or opensource.